# installing php gd on ubuntu on a vps server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I was working on `localhost` with resizing images and everything was great. Then I uploaded to my server and things got interesting. After searching around, looks like I have to enable `php-gd` on my server.

I tried running the line `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` using `putty`, and it didn't work. Any ideas why?

Also, after the install, I assume I will need to run the function sudo reboot right? Clearly I'm not an expert in this area. :P

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What message did you get? If it installed successfuly and GD still doesn't work, you have to reboot Apache by executing `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart`. You shouldn't reboot the whole machine for that, just a particular service which is Apache in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting your Apache daemon by executing `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart` if the installation of `php5-gd` went well. If it didn't, then execute `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` again.